# Is there a function to get the maximum graph out of several graphs?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Is it possible somehow to make a maximum graph out of several other graphs in excel like the red dashed line in the example? I'm trying to automate the graph making via vba and can't figure out this.

[image: example]

Comment: managed to find a way to do it if anyone is interested. found the power functions of straight lines since its a log-log graph. calculated the points every 50ish or so Hz (x axis) and picked out max values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create a maximum graph out of the graphs of two datasets.

However, it is possible to use the `=MAX()` worksheet function to create a new dataset and make a graph out of that newly generated dataset:

[image]